By changing image name I get container crashloopback error
I am facing an issue if I use the ubuntu or centos image the container shows error: crashbackloop.
however if i use apache HTTPD image it works. can you please help me to solve the issue
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
   name: mydeploy
spec:
   replicas: 1
   selector:
    matchLabels:
     name: deployment
   template:
     metadata:
       name: testpod8
       labels:
         name: deployment
     spec:
      containers:
        - name: c00
          image: ubuntu                            ########(htttpd works)
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
            requests:
              cpu: 200m


A container is a wrapper around a single process; it doesn't make sense to "run Ubuntu" in a container without naming some specific process to run.  The base ubuntu Docker image is pretty minimal and you almost always need a more involved custom image with more things involved in it.
